# All variables i call from my class gets the value Null or 0

Tags: android, variables

My application starts from an Main activity and this main activity has its own onTouchListener which is in its own class and from this onTouchClass im calling an AlertDialog when the finger was removed from the screen and its working.. And from this AlertDialog i have an intent that starts activity two.

But i have two variables in the onTouch class that i will need in activity two, So i tried in my AlertDialog initiate the onTouch class and make a .putExtra for each of the variables i need.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(context, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", onTouchClass.integer1);
i.putExtra("Value2", onTouchClass.integer2);
Log.d("Info", "Value1: " + onTouchClass.integer1);
Log.d("Info", "Value2: " + onTouchClass.integer2);
context.startActivity(i);
```

I did logging here and its also 0,On the other side (The activity that gets started) i did this:

```
getValue1 = extras != null? extras.getInt("Value1"): -1;
getValue2 = extras != null? extras.getInt("value2"): -1;
Log.d("Info", "Value1: " + getValue1);
Log.d("Info", "Value2: " + getValue2);
```

Then im taking a look in LogCat for theese logs and it says: Value1: 0 and Value2: 0

And i know there should be a value cus in my onTouchClass i have this which checking if i have a value in it:

```
GeoPoint p = mapview.getProjection().fromPixels((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
integer1 = p.getLatitudeE6();
integer2 = p.getLongitudeE6();
Log.d("Info", "Value1: " + integer1);
Log.d("Info", "Value2: " + integer2);
```

From theese logs in LogCat i do get a value.. But why isn't it working to get this value into the other classes???

Comment: Try logging the value here and let us know what you are getting:

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(context, ActivityTwo.class);

Log.d("Info", "Value1: " + onTouchClass.integer1);
Log.d("Info", "Value2: " + onTouchClass.integer2);
i.putExtra("Value1", onTouchClass.integer1);
i.putExtra("Value2", onTouchClass.integer2);
context.startActivity(i);

Comment: I did logging there as you can see i updated the question. It is also displayed 0

Comment: that means,your updated values in integer1 and integer2 are not reflecting in your AlertDialog itself,which is passed to next activity giving you same result there. Try to use SharedPreference object to store both values and get them in AlertDialog.

Comment: "I did logging here and its also 0", that means the integers are not fetched from the mapview. Somewhere on its way the numbers are lost. Right click the variable and select "Open call stack" or similiar (I'm not at Eclipse now), find all its occurences and log all occurences, and find where it gets 0.

Comment: @Hiral Could you maybe come onto the Android chatroom and we can talk? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass the string value instead of onTouchClass.integer1 this integer value

check what ever the value is store in onTouchClass.integer1.

before pass to the intent print this value and check the log.